# R in Sparklyr cannot return output from lm

Tags: r, sparklyr

I've encountered error for which i cannot find answer on the Internet.
To reproduce the error, just call

```
sc = spark_connect(master = "local")
cars = copy_to(sc, mtcars)
cars %>% spark_apply(~lm(mpg ~.,.x))
```

It throws an error that it cannot open the connection. I'm using win 10, RSTUDIO, sparklyr library.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason is that the spark will output only dataframe, however, lm function returns formatted string.